# CookieParser and CookieSession middleware in Express.js

Tags: node.js, express, node.js-connect

I am trying to use the cookieSession middleware in an Express.js app. Is cookieParser middleware required to use before cookieSession middleware? Also cookieParser accepts a secret key and so does the cookieSession middleware. Do I need to set the secret in both?

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.cookieParser('secret'));
app.use(express.cookieSession({
  key: 'key',
  secret: 'Should it be same as above?'
});
```

I do know that cookieSession middleware assigns cookie variables to the req.sesison object. So I guess cookieParser is required but where should I be setting the secret? Should I set the same secret in both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the catch. Secret string passed to `cookieParser` is not used by it but by other middlewares and is optional for it. It sets `req.secret` to that value. `cookieSession` simply checks if `req.secret` exists and will use it, but by default it will use the secret option passed explicitly over the stored secret. So passing the option to only one of them would suffice.

You can see it in their documentation : [cookieParser](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/cookieParser.html) and [cookieSession](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/cookieSession.html)